# sort data from json according to time in different key in java script?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sorting

{"id":"365","month":"December","date":"30","sehri":"05:40 AM","fajr":"05:46 AM","tulu_e_aaftab":"07:06 AM","makrooh":"11:49 AM","zohar":"12:30 PM","asar":"04:18 PM","magrib":"05:53 PM","isha":"07:13 PM"},{"id":"366","month":"December","date":"31","sehri":"05:40 AM","fajr":"05:46 AM","tulu_e_aaftab":"07:06 AM","makrooh":"11:49 AM","zohar":"12:30 PM","asar":"04:19 PM","magrib":"05:53 PM","isha":"07:13 PM"}

this is json 
i need output like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfHs.png)

Comment: here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property and create a new date with all of your parameters

Answer (score 0):

Given your objects contain multiple datapoints about the date they represent, I recommend using a `Date()` object to store this information. That way you would be able to sort the array simply like this:

```
const sortedDates = arrayOfDateObjects.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
```

Likewise if you wanted to preserve your object format, you can use the Date object only within the sort function:

```
const sortedDates = originalArray.sort((a, b) => {
    let dateA = new Date();
    // extract the date from a and apply it to dateA
    let dateB = new Date();
    // extract the date from b and apply it to dateB
    return dateA - dateB
});
```

You can find out more information about the Date object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)